# Use CSS rule on Mouse hover

Tags: javascript, css

I have a dial that moves automatically, and I would like to figure out a way to have it move only when the mouse hovers over the div. I have read that it may not be possible to do this in javascript, but I am hoping some one here might have a solution.

Here is what I have so far.
https://jsfiddle.net/r0w71wkv/

```
#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#logo .speedometer {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;

}
#logo .needle {
    width: 5px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #324A90;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-animation:move 5s infinite;
    transform:rotate(0deg);
    transform-origin:bottom;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {
        transform:rotate(-180deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform:rotate(90deg);
        }
    100% {
        transform:rotate(-180deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **:hover** Psudeoclass
>
> Only active when the element preceding it is being hovered.

Using `:hover`:

```
#logo .needle:hover {
    -webkit-animation:move 5s infinite;
    animation:move 5s infinite;
}
```

Then get rid of the `-webkit-animation` that you have currently. This will play the move animation only when you hover over the `.needle` element in `#logo`.

Also, you don't need to prefix `animation` much anymore: http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20animation

Here's  a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r0w71wkv/5/.

I might note that you could be better off first setting the width and the height of the `#mainwrap` div, and then using `#mainwrap:hover .needle`, because that way the user doesn't have to hover *directly* over the needle. This would like: https://jsfiddle.net/r0w71wkv/6/.

Comment: I have tried using .needle:hover, but I just lose the animation all together. Same when I lose the webkit.

Comment: @user2168066 Try using https://jsfiddle.net/r0w71wkv/7/. I think the problem is that you have to hover *exactly* over the needle with the other approach, when this in fact defines an 80px by 80px area where you can hover to play the animation.

Comment: Ok I see now, the problem was having to hover directly over the specific div, thanks for the help.